# How do I recover reference to this$0 in a nested class?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to know if there is a way to recover a reference "manually" of the `this$0`, in other words, to the outer class in a nested class?

This means references to any method or attribute of the outer class using the name or `methodOuterClass()` or `OuterClass.this.Method()` result in a `NullPointerException`.

Due to the problems listed below, e.g. Gson, construct objects without reference to the outer class. It is possible to repair this after the object has being created?

**References**

[GSON does not deserialize reference to outer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449761/gson-does-not-deserialize-reference-to-outer-class)

[using member of outer class in a inner class makes null exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809866/using-member-of-outer-class-in-a-inner-class-makes-null-exception?noredirect=1#comment55388029_33809866)

Comment: did you try using reflection? i.e. `Field field = Outer.Inner.class.getDeclaredField("this$0"); field.setAccessible(true); field.set(inner, outer);`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios it works, put it as answer if you want the credit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@BeyelerStudios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825261/recovering-reference-to-this0-in-a-nested-class#comment55416194_33825261), unfortunately, he didn't put his comment as an answer.

I am putting an answer with example code:

```
public class Outer {     
    protected Inner inner = null; 
    public Inner getInner() {
        return inner;
    }      
    protected void something(){ }
    public void function(){
       inner.fixParent(this); // solve the reference lost
       inner.innerFunction(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "{\"inner\":{\"name\"=\"test\"}}";
        Outer outer = (new Gson()).fromJson(str,Outer.class);
        System.out.println(outer.getInner().name);
        outer.function();
    }

    public class Inner {
        public String name = null;

        private void fixParent(Outer parent){// solution here
            try {
                field = Inner.class.getDeclaredField("this$0");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(this, parent);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
        protected void innerFunction(){
            Field field = null;                       
            something();//now works 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a phenomenon that I encountered:

- An inner class that is Serializable
  -The outer class is not

After **deserializing** and **serializing** again of the inner classes object,

- the `OuterClass.this` was `null`.

The inner class should probably have been made static. Or *very expensive,* the outer class made Serializable.

Evidently you need the `OuterClass`. If you got the serialized file, you might be able to create a patching inner class, with same serialVersionUID and convert it to a correct variant of the class under other name.

That would be some accomplishment. It might be easier to transfer such a wrong instance to a new classes object.

Comment: is that even possible?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422665/is-it-possible-to-serialize-anonymous-class-without-outer-class

Comment: @AdamSkywalker now it was legacy software with a NPE of the `Outer.this` before a long time. I was very incredulous; still in fact, Now I can no longer say whether the class definitions changed in any way - between serialization and deserialization. "One could try it out"